# Best way to save data Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What is the best way to store data of a lambda function invocation? And should it be done inside the function itself extending duration time, or outside and store data asynchronously?

What I have:
A simple Lambda function that returns some data from an api to the user. (no stats are saved)

What I want:
A Lambda function that also stores data/stats without impacting the runtime of the main function. Can this be done?

Can I pass event data to another lambda function as destination? For example: a StoreStatsFunction that connects with a DB that runs asynchronously? Or maybe: pass the data as metrics to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

You can create logic in your Lambda function to persist the data anywhere you want. For example, maybe you want to encode your data to JSON then save the data in DynamoDB so another Lambda function or another AWS Service you code can query that data and use it. Purhaps you want to store your data in an AWS RDS instance. You can build your Lambda to handle data in any manner to address your business requirements.

Also - you asked if one Lambda function can generate data and pass it to another Lambda function. The answer is yes. In fact, when you build a workflow using Lambda and AWS Step functions, that is what typically happens. One workflow step can generate data and pass that data to another step in the AWS Workflow.

To see how this can be done, may i suggest that you read this doc:

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS step function with [synchronous](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/) invocation.

You can add a state in your step function state machine to put data to some [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html) table if you don't want to do any further processing on request or response

or

to [SQS or SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html) where you can you can trigger another lambda which can save the request/response asynchronously without impacting you main function.

[Lambda destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) is only supported for asynchronous invocations.